# If statements cause app to crash

Tags: java, android, if-statement, crash

I'm working on an app that involved comparing to numbers inputted by the user via text box, but wen I put in any if statements the program crashes whenever they are called. Otherwise the program runs just fine without any crashes or errors.

```
    package improvecredit.app.basic;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImprovrCreditBasicActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public int minCredScore = 300;
public int maxCredScore = 850;
public int inputScore;
public int idealScore;

public Editable inputString;
public Editable idealString;

public EditText user;
public EditText desired;
public TextView output;

public Button submit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_text);
    desired = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desired_text);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_text);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button); 

    //submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //inputString = user.getText();
            //idealString = desired.getText();

            inputScore = Integer.getInteger(user.getText().toString());
            idealScore = Integer.getInteger(desired.getText().toString());

            if (inputScore >= 0 && idealScore >= 0){

                if (inputScore < minCredScore || idealScore < minCredScore){
                    output.setText("Invalid Entries");
                }
                if (inputScore > maxCredScore || idealScore > maxCredScore){
                    output.setText("Invalid Entries");
                }
                if (inputScore > idealScore){
                    output.setText("Nice Credit Score!");
                }
                if (inputScore < idealScore){
                    output.setText("For more information on how to improve your credit score, please visit" + "/n" + "http://www.creditscoresandcredit.com/");
                }
            }
            else{
                output.setText("Please enter valid credit scores");
            }
        }
    });         
}
```

If someone can point out what may have been done wrong in the code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace; it's unlikely the `if` statement itself is causing a crash. More likely to be the integer parsing, output text setting, etc.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Check to make sure inputScore and idealScore have values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On first glance, don't use Integer.getInteger(), use Integer.parseInt().

If that doesn't fix it, please include the crash log from the console so we can see exactly what exception is being raised.

Comment: This is correct. getInteger does not do what it sounds like it might do. From javadoc: getInteger - "Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name."

Comment: @Dave and Geekswordsman: I tried out both of your suggestions and they seem to have solved the problem. Thanks guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that there is a null value introduced.  If you check for null before using the variables idealScore and inputScore in the If statement, it will avoid this error.  Until you paste the error trace, we can only guess for you.

Comment: An int will never be null. Null check would be pointless and also won't work.